# Ambiguity with Bluetooth mouse

Tags: bluetooth, mouse

I'm running Kubuntu 21.10.  My Bluetooth mouse shows up in the Devices list twice: both as a BT3.0 mouse and a BT5.2 mouse, and I can't connect to it.  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to have resolved itself; the 3.0 mouse just went away.  But if it hadn't, I think I could have solved the issue by removing it explicitly with the remove option in the mouse's menu.